# browserHistory not working ( ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Pages switching normaly, but URL doesn't change when click to another page, and after refreshing page, I redirect to the home page

my index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    render
} from 'react-dom'
import {
    Provider as ReduxProvider
} from 'react-redux'
// import { Provider as IntlProvider } from './components/Intl'
import {
    Router,
    Route,
    IndexRoute,

    Link,
    Redirect,
    browserHistory
} from 'react-router'


import  App  from './containers/App'
import  Home  from './containers/Home/Home'
import  Course  from './containers/Course/Course'
import  Feedback  from './containers/Feedback/Feedback'
import  Revenue from './containers/Revenue/Revenue'
import  Income from './containers/Revenue/Income'
import  IncomeOver from './containers/Revenue/IncomeOver'


import {
    routerMiddleware
} from 'react-router-redux'

import {
    IntlProvider,
    addLocaleData
} from 'react-intl'
import en from 'react-intl/locale-data/en'
import zh from 'react-intl/locale-data/zh'
addLocaleData([...en, ...zh])




import {
    createStore,
    compose,
    applyMiddleware
} from 'redux'
import Immutable from 'immutable'
import {
    combineReducers
} from 'redux-immutable'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
render((
    <ReduxProvider >
        <IntlProvider locale={'en'}>
          <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                <Route path="Course" component={Course}/>
                <Route path="Feedback" component={Feedback}/>
                <Route path="/Revenue" component={Revenue}>
                    <IndexRoute component={Income}/>
                    <Route path="Income" component={Income}/>
                    <Route path="IncomeOver" component={IncomeOver}/>

                </Route>
            </Route>

          </Router>
        </IntlProvider>
  </ReduxProvider>
), document.getElementById('mount'))
```

Pages in Nav bar look like this:

```
<li><Link to="/Revenue" activeClassName="activelink">REVENUE MANAGEMENT</Link></li>
```

Why I don't get URL, When I move to another page?

Comment: I don't see `/students` listed in your route config?

Comment: <li><Link to="/Revenue" activeClassName="activelink">REVENUE MANAGEMENT</Link></li> for example